# If an aerofoil is placed in a narrow wind tunnel, how will that affect the lift it produces?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, ground-effect, wind-tunnel

### This is [NACA 0000](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NACA_0000.svg) aerofoil:

[image: A line]

This is just a straight line - roughly what a paper plane's aerofoil section looks like (I chose this aerofoil for its simplicity). If we put this aerofoil in a wind tunnel, then this is my approximation of what the air-flow around it might look like:

<sup>(Infinite wind tunnel - ignore ground effect)</sup>
[image: 2]
$$(AoA=12°)$$

The air-flow isn't ideal; there is flow seperation already at the leading edge. But still, the aerofoil will produce a net positive lift.

But what happens if we put this aerofoil in a narrow wind tunnel?
[image]
The pressure distribution appears to have been reversed: high pressure above and low pressure below.

This is explained as follows: *through a convergent duct, the air-flow velocity (and thus dynamic pressure) increases. This is accompanied by a reduction in static pressure, such that the total pressure remains constant (the opposite is true for a divergent duct).*

**Is this true? and so will the aerofoil produce a downforce instead of lift in the narrow wind tunnel?**

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider more than just the static pressure. In the usual demonstrations of the Bernoulli effect, the pressure tap is placed perpendicular to the streamlines, which means it only "feels" the static pressure, but an object placed directly in the middle of the streamlines acts as a "stagnation point," and feels an additional pressure associated with actually forcing the streamlines to take a different path.

A small hole perpendicular to the streamlines can be used to measure the static pressure. A small hole placed parallel to the streamlines at a point where the streamlines are forced to stop can be used to measure the stagnation pressure. In this case, the airfoil is neither parallel nor perpendicular to the streamlines, and the resultant pressure will be somewhere in between the two.

Comment: Yes, but what will be the net effect? will the lift reduce due to change in pressure distribution? will it stay same? (or will it increase due to ground effect?)

Comment: @AdityaSharma The lower wall should increase the lift due to ground effect. The upper wall should decrease the lift. The net effect probably depends on the actual distances.

Comment: Alright, so if we remove the lower wall, the lift should reduce. By the way, I believe that the upper wall will also contribute towards "ground" effect, since it is also limiting the downwash, just like the lower wall (think of a Formula 1 car that uses ground effect to improve downforce - this is a similar case, just inverted). So if the F1 car with the same setup achieves an increase in lift (downforce), why would our setup suffer from a decrease in lift?

Comment: @AdityaSharma Hmm, I think you're right, actually. (The bit about the upper wall I was not so sure about to begin with). In that case, both the floor and the ceiling would increase the lift and it makes the overall effect much easier to figure out.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I thought when I first came across this problem, but then I thought: *How would the apparent "reversal" of pressure distribution (as explained by Bernoulli's principle) affect the lift?* - This is something I was never able to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where working backwards from actual wind tunnel data may be more helpful.

A *higher* pressure stagnation zone will form underneath the plate.  This is the ground effect, increasing lift.  Air velocity will *increase* at the *exit* of this area (at the trailing edge).

A *lower* pressure area forms above the plate, with a *lower* (or even reverse) air flow at its exit.  This will increase lift.

The Formula 1 car is producing *downforce* (or a reverse ground effect).

So, Bernoulli can't explain everything.  Local **pressure** may be a more accurate way to predict lifting effects.

However, if a more smoothly *cambered* [airfoil](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=clarky-il) is chosen, interference with upper airflow may indeed reduce lift, especially at higher Reynolds numbers.

Comment: Read on about biplane wing interference effects.

Comment: "*A higher pressure stagnation zone will form underneath the plate.*" - but the pressure never increases at the entrance of a Venturi, it only decreases, there is no stagnation (based on my limited knowledge of the Venturi effect). What would make this setup different from a Venturi?

Comment: @AdityaSharma it may be that the *trailing edge* is where velocity increases, and pressure decreases.  The upper wall may indeed reduce lift (even with the flat plate).  I think the upper wall may cause a stall at a lower AoA.

Comment: "*It may be that the trailing edge is where velocity increases, and pressure decreases.*" - In my opinion, that shouldn't be the case. To justify my opinion, I would first like to summarise why the velocity increases and pressure decreases in a Venturi. There are two principles in action: 1) Law of conservation of mass, and 2) Bernoulli's principle. Law 1 tells us that mass flow rate (of an ideal fluid) through a streamtube will always be equal at every section of the tube. This implies that if the section area decreases, velocity must increase for the mass flow rate to remain constant.

Comment: Law 2 tells us that the increase in velocity produces an increase in dynamic pressure. Now, the static pressure must reduce for the total pressure to remain constant. Based on this description of the venturi effect, the increase in dynamic pressure and decrease in static pressure must take place gradually as the section area reduces, not suddenly at the choke (trailing edge).

Comment: @AdityaSharma: there's a misunderstanding here. In a venturi tube the whole airflow flows inside it but in your picture "half" of the air is going over the plate and the other half under it: that's definitely not a venturi. Due to the blockage effect of the bottom wall I'd expect a lower speed on the belly i.e. a higher pressure and therefore lift.

Comment: @sophit yes, what is pictured seems more like a throttle (air inlet) plate on a carburetor.  That swirly area above and behind the plate trailing edge might be a good place to inject fuel.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni: yep, "butterfly valve" might be a good starting point to understand that airflow

Comment: @sophit you say that it cannot be considered a Venturi since not all of the flow is entering it. Admittedly, I do not understand how the flow would behave at the entrance of the "butterfly valve", but **after** half of the flow has entered the "duct" (formed by the "butterfly valve" and the wind tunnel walls), what would prevent the duct from behaving like a Venturi?

Comment: @AdityaSharma look at a stone in a river.  The *momentum* of incoming fluid creates a rise in pressure when any obstacle slows it.  Consider each half of a Venturi as an obstacle.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni But then what we observe in practice is that the static pressure *decreases* and the velocity *increases* through the Venturi. The same will happen around the stone. The velocity of water flow must be increased in order for a constant mass flow rate to be maintained at each section of the river. If flow doesn't speed up through a constriction, then that would violate the law of conservation of mass. You are right about that static pressure will be higher than free flow at the stagnation point, but then it will be lower than free flow around the stone.

Comment: @AdityaSharma then there is an alternative: mass flow is *not* constant.  Water can "back up" behind a dam.  Pressure can rise with air.  Interestingly,  keep the walls, but remove the two Venturi halves.  Now glue the long ends back together.  Looks like a airfoil.  Now put that back in the tunnel.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni "*Then there is an alternative: mass flow is not constant*" But then what about the law of conservation of mass? If the flow is backing up behind the dam, it's also backing up at the source, and at all points between the dam and the source. Even after the dam, the mass flow rate will be the same as that before the dam. If mass flow rate is altered at one point, it will be altered at all points within the stream (unless there is change in density resulting from change in pressure, an effect which is generally negligible in aerodynamics at speeds below Mach 0.3).

Comment: @AdityaSharma while the pressure is building the mass flow in the system may not be constant.  But once the pressure is high enough to force sufficient flow through the venturi then mass flow becomes constant:  flow in = flow out.  But we know (with our kitchen sink) if inflow is too great, and the drain too small, it overflows!  Is not a wind tunnel analysis where *steady state* is reached?  I think this is why a *higher pressure stagnation area* exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146347/discussion-between-aditya-sharma-and-robert-digiovanni).

Comment: @AdityaSharma because the flow is subsonic: what happens in one point downstream depends on what happen upstream. If upstream half of the flow goes somewhere else then you have already lost the definition of Venturi and whatever happens downstream cannot be anymore related to a Venturi.

Comment: @sophit Then perhaps even [Venturi tubes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect%23Experimental_apparatus&ved=2ahUKEwj-0OXI15z_AhWKV2wGHRBCDIYQ0gIoAXoECEYQAg&usg=AOvVaw3AR7CN_86I7Z4XvlHk4OCL) cannot be considered "Venturi", since some of the upstream flow enters them and some does not. Lets not call my apparatus a Venturi then, we'll call it a convergent duct instead. So how will the flow behave through this convergent duct, as far as it's static and dynamic pressures are concerned?